# Replacing Column Name with Loop in R

Tags: r

I have three df P1,P2,P3 with each three columns. I want to change the second column from each df to D1, D2, D3 with a loop but nothing is working. What do I miss out?

```
C1 <- c(12,34,22)
C2 <- c(43,86,82)
C3 <- c(98,76,25)

C4 <- c(12,34,22)
C5 <- c(43,86,82)
C6 <- c(98,76,25)

C7 <- c(12,34,22)
C8 <- c(43,86,82)
C9 <- c(98,76,25)

P1 <- data.frame(C1,C2,C3)
P2 <- data.frame(C4,C5,C6)
P3 <- data.frame(C7,C8,C9)

x <- c("P1", "P2", "P3")
b <- c("D1","D2","D3")

for (V in b){
  names(x)[2] <- "V"
}
```

The output I would expect is:

```
P1 <- data.frame(C1,D1,C3)
P2 <- data.frame(C4,D2,C6)
P3 <- data.frame(C7,D3,C9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the string vector in a `list`, use `Map` to rename the second column each of the `list` element with the corresponding 'b' value, then use `list2env` to update those objects in the global env

```
list2env(Map(function(x, y) {names(x)[2] <- y; x}, mget(x), b), .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
P1
#  C1 D1 C3
#1 12 43 98
#2 34 86 76
#3 22 82 25

P2
#  C4 D2 C6
#1 12 43 98
#2 34 86 76
#3 22 82 25
P3
#  C7 D3 C9
#1 12 43 98
#2 34 86 76
#3 22 82 25
```

---

For understanding the code, first step is `mget` on the vector of strings

```
mget(x)
```

returns a `list` of data.frame

Then, we are passing this as argument to `Map` along with the corresponding 'b' vector.  i.e. each element of `list` is a unit, similarly each element of `vector` is a unit

```
Map(function(x, y) x, mget(x), b)
```

The `function(x, y)` is anonymous/lambda function construct.  Using that we set the `names` of the second column to that of 'b'.  Here, the anonymous argument for 'b' is 'y'.  Later, we wrap everything in `list2env` as it is a named `list` and it will look up for those names in the global env to update it

Comment: It's working but I need to digest it before I understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is usually best to work with lists for this type of thing. That can make life easier and is generally a good workflow to learn.

```r
list1 <- list(P1 = P1, P2 = P2, P3 = P3)

# here is your loop
for (i in seq_along(list1)) {
  names(list1[[i]])[2] <- b[i]
}

# you can use Map as well for iteration, similar to @akrun's solution
# this is really identical at this point, except you've created the list differently
Map(function(df, b) {names(df)[2] <- b; df}, list1, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for you example. Is "V" in your example basically "b"?
```
lapply(list1, function(df) {names(df)[2] <- "V"; df})
```

Comment: Basically I am just suggesting you create the list on your own and work with the data that way, rather then trying to find variables in the environment and writing them back to it.